# What dtype should I use for PyTorch parameters in a neural network that inputs and outputs arrays of integers?

Tags: integer, precision, numeric, pytorch, continuous

I'm currently building a neural network in PyTorch that accepts tensors of **integers** and outputs tensors of **integers**.  There is only a *small number of positive integers that are "allowed"*  (like 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4) as elements of the input and output tensors.

Neural networks usually work in continuous space.
For example, the nonlinear activation functions between layers are continuous and map integers to real numbers (including non-integers).

Is it best to use unsigned integers like `torch.uint8` internally for the weights and biases of the network plus some custom activation function that maps ints to ints?

Or should I use high precision floats like `torch.float32` and then round in the end, by binning real numbers to the nearest integer?  I think this second strategy is the way to go, but maybe I'm missing out on something that would work nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing too much about your application I would go for `torch.float32` with rounding. The main reason being that if you use a GPU to compute your neural network, it will require wights and data to be in `float32` datatype. If you are not going to train your neural network and you want to run on CPU, then datatypes like `torch.uint8` may help you as you can achieve more instructions per time interval (i.e. your application should run faster). If that doesn't leave you with a clue, then please be more specific about your application.

Comment: I am pretty sure pytorch will just blow up in your face if you use integers anyways, since the gradients are kind of discontinuous as well, then.

Comment: @dennlinger On CPU for inference it might work, that's why I asked about the objective.

Comment: Thanks so much, I hadn't considered using floats and rounding for training then switching to ints on CPU for inference.  This answers my question exactly.